# What does this command mean ls -l test.conf -rw-r--r-- l root root?

Tags: command-line, openvpn

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/openvpn# ls -l test.conf -rw-r--r-- l root root 791 Mar 20 09:23 test.conf
```

What does the above command mean?

Comment: While we tend to encourage exploring and trying things on your Ubuntu system, you probably shouldn't be doing that as "root"

Comment: @ BryceAtNetwork23: Thanks for the tip but I was given the instruction to do that.

Answer (score 11):

That is not a command. It *contains* a command.

It's a prompt, followed by a command, followed by the output of the command. The command itself is:

```
ls -l test.conf
```

That command displays information about the file called `test.conf` located in the [current directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_directory). [The `ls` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ls.1.html) displays (or *lists*) information about files. The `-l` flag makes it display the information in long form, rather than just showing the filename.

(`ls` without a flag like `-l` is most often used to list multiple files or determine if a file exists, but may be used with a file known to exist; by default in Ubuntu, issuing `ls filename` will highlight *`filename`* in a way that shows what kind of file it is, for example, it will use a certain color if it is a directory, another if it is marked executable.)

The output is:

```
-rw-r--r-- l root root 791 Mar 20 09:23 test.conf
```

That means the file:

- is not a [directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28file_systems%29) (`-rw-r--r--` doesn't start with `d`)
- is non-[setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) and non-setgid (no `s` in `-rw-r--r--`) and non-[sticky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) (no `t`)
- is readable and writeable by its owner (`rw-` for owner) but only readable by other users (`r--` for group members, `r--` again for others) — see [the community documentation on permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)
- is [owned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150028/you-are-not-the-owner-message-when-trying-to-access-folder/150033#150033) by the user [`root`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) (with `root` as its [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28computing%29) identity also)
- is 791 [bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) in [size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_size)
- reports that it was last modified (or created) on the 20th of March at 9:23 am
- has the name `test.conf`

The *beginning* of the line is a prompt; this is what is displayed to the user in a shell to notify the user they may enter a command. Prompts are often configured to provide helpful information to the user. Here the prompt is:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/openvpn#
```

This means the current user is `root`, the machine's hostname is `ubuntu` (which usually means this is a [live CD/DVD/USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) system, but someone could name their machine `ubuntu` in an installed system too), and the current directory is `/etc/openvpn` (which is where configuration data for [OpenVPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN) are stored, see also the [Ubuntu OpenVPN documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openvpn.html)).

The `#` character indicates that this is a [superuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) shell (which is to be expected as it is owned by root, [the superuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like)); otherwise it would have been `$` (but please note that this convention is not universally followed, and some shells default to `%` which does not indicate anything about the shell's capabilities).

Comment: I've edited the post slightly to account for what looks like a botched copypaste. Your post should still make sense.

Comment: @ Oli: While I appreciate your good intention, I would appreciate it if you could edit it back to the original phrase/sentence. I copied exactly what was displayed on my computer screen. If you have any issue with it, you could point it out in your answer or comment.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you have a misunderstanding with the *structure* of that line.

The first sentence is telling **the user** at a determined **computer** that is in the mentioned **folder**:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/openvpn#
```

Here you have:

1. user = "root"
2. machine name = "ubuntu"
3. location = "/etc/openvpn"

and the corresponding separators between them are `@`, `:` and `#`

The command, that is after the last separator (`#`), is:

```
ls -l test.conf
```

The output that you get is:

```
-rw-r--r-- l root root 791 Mar 20 09:23 test.conf
```