# Running applications as different users

Tags: playonlinux

1. Can we run the same application under different users? Ex: App1 running under both `/home/usr1/App1` and `/home/Usr2/App1` on a Linux platform?
2. Can we have Same UID for two different users? Ex: `/home/usr1/App1` and `/home/usr2/App2`
   i.e Usr1 and  Usr2 having same UID?? If yes then how to do it?
3. Can an application switch from one user to another, e.g., app1 running under `/home/usr1` can switch to `/home/usr2`

Comment: Hello, Welcome to askubuntu. This Q&A site is meant for ubuntu related queries. So it would be better if you ask this question in sister site like Unix Stack Exchange. Also the rule says, Don't add many queries in one question. Please a have look at [FAQ]. I am flagging this question for migration to Unix SE site.

Comment: @Web-E Why do you think this is not about Ubuntu?

Comment: @EliahKagan well I have the same reservation as web-e. The questions 1 and 3 are well... weird. They lack something but I can not get my finger on what it is it is lacking.

Comment: No sir, @EliahKagan I was creating an answer (but yours is better so I gave up on that ;) )

Answer (score 2):

It's best to post separate questions separately. However, since these can all be answered quickly (and are related), I've done so.

1. The same application may be run by different users, at different times, or at the same time. The application may run *from the same location* (so long as both users have access to execute it), or separate copies may be run from different locations (as in your example).
2. Two different users *cannot* share a UID. Your UID is actually more central to your user identity (hence the name) than your username. When you [own a file or folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150028/you-are-not-the-owner-message-when-trying-to-access-folder/150033#150033), the filesystem contains your UID associated with the file, not your username. Having two users with the same UID would mean having a single user with multiple names (which is also not supported).
3. Yes, it is possible to switch user identity. You can use `sudo -u other-user command...` or (if you are currently `root`, or if the target user has login enabled and you know their password) `su other-user -c 'command...'`. You can invoke these commands yourself, but scripts and applications can also use them.

   See [the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html), and [`man su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/su.1.html) for more details on how this works and how to use it. In a program you are writing, you can also use the `setuid` function; see [`man 2 setuid`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man2/setuid.2.html) and [`man 3 setuid`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/setuid.3posix.html). To run graphical applications, you should use `gksu`/`gksudo` or (in Kubuntu) `kdesudo` instead of invoking `su` and `sudo` directly (but please note that by default in Ubuntu `gksu` invokes `sudo`, not `su`). See [this section of the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo), [`man gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html) (covers `gksudo` too), and [`man kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/kdesudo.1.html).

   Before writing programs or scripts that change users, I recommend reading up extensively on how user identity works in Unix-like systems.

Comment: Point 2 can be solved with a group ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind A group can't make multiple users have the same UID, which is the question asked. I'm not sure what the intent is, so I'm not sure if a group would do what the OP needs. But you may want to post an answer that includes information about groups. (Or if you prefer to edit this CW answer, of course feel free, but I know you had said you'd been composing an answer...).