# sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0

Tags: permissions, sudo

Whenever I try to do anything at all that requires my password it returns this:

```
u7ur7l3@ubuntu:~$ sudo
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
u7ur7l3@ubuntu:~$
```

So I can't install anything from the Software Center / package manager or run any commands in terminal that require my password. I can log in, but that's pretty much it.

I accidentally changed the permissions of some files, then changed some more trying to fix it :/. Now I'm completely lost as to what to do.

This is what happened when I tried to get sudo working again using pkexec:

```
u7ur7l3@ubuntu:~$ pkexec chown root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success 

u7ur7l3@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0 sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

And to change permissions I was using Root Actions as a dolphin service/ plugin thing, so history doesn't show me the permission changes.

I just realized that sounds don't work at all anymore. When I go into Phonon my default settings and playback devices aren't even there. Also I don't have the option to shutdown, I can only log out or leave.

Comment: Is the sound and shutdown problem new *since* you ran the `pkexec` command?

Comment: @Eliah Kagan, no I realized the sound issue right when I logged on to my computer, and I realized the shutdown issue when I was turning my computer off last night. I ended up just holding down the power button.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to provide instructions that *should* work even though neither `sudo` and PolicyKit (via `pkexec`) work.

Comment: su root
chown -R root:root /usr/lib/

Comment: I [solved it on kali linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590463/415852) [thus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590463/415852) [https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590463/415852](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590463/415852)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Ownership](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150028/you-are-not-the-owner-message-when-trying-to-access-folder/150033#150033) of at least one of your important system files is wrong. That's a bad thing; if this has happened to many system files (perhaps you ran a big `sudo chown` command with the `-R` flag at some point?), it could cause a number of other system errors and instabilities. So *if you recently installed Ubuntu*, you might want to reinstall as [Adam Heathcote suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/277012/22949).

But **you do not have to reinstall to fix this problem**. Instead, just fix the ownership on that file. If you get errors about other files after that, you can fix them too (though you might have to tell us what the error messages are, so we can tell you how to fix them also).

[`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) does not work, but [using `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) is [one of *two* ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi/73872#73872) for [administrators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245201/how-to-not-become-a-root-user-are-administrators-root/245262#245262) to perform actions as [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_user#Unix_and_Unix-like) on Ubuntu. The other is [Polkit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html) (which used to be called PolicyKit).

Run this command, which uses Polkit (via [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html)) to change the ownership of `/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so` back to `root` (i.e., uid 0):

```
pkexec chown root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Then try using `sudo` again. You can run something trivial like `sudo ls`, and see if you get an error message.

Finally, I recommend running `history` to reveal all the commands you've run. Hopefully that will list all the commands you've run that have changed permissions. Assuming `sudo` now works, I recommend posting a new question including the output of `history`, to get help undoing *all* the file ownership and permissions changes you've done.

### If `pkexec` doesn't work either...

You tried `pkexec` and it didn't work. Since neither `sudo` nor Polkit is working to allow you to perform actions as root, you'll have to boot into recovery mode and get a root shell. To do this, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting up your computer, to ensure you get a visible GRUB boot menu. Select an entry that contains the words *recovery mode* (generally, you should select the one closest to the top that has those words). Then you'll get a menu where you have a number of options--select the option to drop to a root shell.

Detailed instructions on accessing a root shell in recovery mode are here:

- [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

Once you have a root shell, run:

```
chown root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

If you get an error about the file or filesystem not being modifiable, then remount it readwrite:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

(Source for the idea of remounting and how to do it: [this mostly unrelated answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/275988/22949).)

Then after running that `mount` command, run the above `chown` command again and see if it works.

Once you're done in recovery mode you can reboot by running:

```
reboot
```

`sudo` should then work, or at least give some *other* error.

Finally, please note that given the errors you showed, it's likely that many files now have the wrong ownership or permissions. It would be ideal if you could figure out which files you modified in this way. For example, if you could figure out that it was all files in a couple specific folders, then it might be possible to correct the complete extent of the recent problems you've been having.

Reinstalling is definitely an option, but especially if all you changed was *ownership* (and not permissions, which are somewhat harder to reconstruct as they vary more), it should be possible to simply set the permissions back recursively to their original owners (probably usually root) and reverse the damage entirely.

Getting `sudo` working again is a first step. Hopefully the above technique will enable you to do that.

Comment: I followed those instructions but when I booted back into kubuntu to problem still existed. Same error. At this point it's probably easier to just re-install. :/

Comment: Also, is there any way I can do something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc to save everything? The all together as a pseudo-bash script won't work because sudo is involved so....

Comment: @7UR7L3 That will back up information about what packages are installed, and *most* information about your programs' systemwide settings. In combination with a full backup of your home directory, that should enable you to restore things mostly to the way they were, after removing the existing system and installing a new one, yes. Please make sure to have a backup of all truly important files (like your documents) at all times. If you find you need more information about that technique as applied to your situation, I suggest posting a new question (but I don't mind if you ask in comments here).

Comment: Is there a good way to go about all this? I have a 1 TB external drive that I can back up stuff to, but It won't appear anywhere when I plug it in. It's light is on to show that it works but nothing on the screen is changing and it's not anywhere in dolphin. Then once I get that working how should I go about saving everything to it. In the package manager I could save the installed packages to a text document, but that's really all that I've figured out to do to save information. Pretty much all other solutions involve sudo which still won't work.

Comment: @7UR7L3 For backing up files? Boot from a live CD/DVD or live USB. You can access your files from there, and back them up to your external drive. If your external drive doesn't appear in the live system either, then that's a totally separate problem which I might not be able to help you with and almost certainly couldn't within the confines of comments. So if that happens, I recommend posting a new question. If you comment here with a link to the new question, I'll make sure to look at it and contribute if I can.

Comment: Just using `chown root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so` was not enough.  I needed to use also `sudo chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/*` and `sudo chmod a+x /usr/lib/sudo/sash`, and now it works.  Anyway after doing that, my HD is shown as full after rebooting the OS. I can remove some files, but it gets full again.

Comment: chown got `cannot access ‘/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so’: No such file or directory` . What's the problem?