# Help me win this war!

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, sudo, users

History:

- The *map*: I have a dual-booted laptop, Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu
  14.04. For Ubuntu, I have a separate partition, which stores my data.
- The *enemy*: `sudo chown -R hadoopuser /`, which literally took down
  my entire base.

---

Current state:

I installed Ubuntu again, overwriting my old installation. However the partition with the data is still there, I can see the data, but I can not for example create a folder there, since the message "you are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions." appears at the bottom of the folder. From properties, I can see that the Owner is `user #1001`.

---

Next move?

1. Act like Alexander The Great: Assault the data partition, kill the `user #1001`, or at least make negotiations, so that I, user `gsamaras` can use this partition as a place to save my documents, etc..

*OR*

2. Act like a Spartan: Annihilate the data partition and extend
   Ubuntu's partition, so that it will take over that space.

What would you suggest me to do? It will be very helpful if you could point on how to implement the suggestion you made.

---

I found this question ["You are not the owner..." message when trying to access folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150028/you-are-not-the-owner-message-when-trying-to-access-folder), but I cannot relate.

<sub>I am just using the names of these Ancient warriors, because I am Greek.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a file manager and click on the partition to mount it. Then, run the following command to gain full ownership of the partition and all contained files:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/$USER/*
```

or,

```
sudo chown -R gsamaras:gsamaras "/media/gsamaras/a6cd1464-abf1-4a7b-b4a2-61f584d4cb32"
```

Comment: When I open the Home folder, I can also see the disk of my Windows, so I think your answer doesn't address me directly. Moreover, I do not how to do what you are saying, or how to check `/etc/fstab`, so any step-by-step approach will help on not wrecking anything..again. Sorry for being scholastic, but I am afraid.

Comment: I said that it does not because of this "The following command assumes the data partition is the only external or extra mounted partition." and I do not have two mounted "things there"...Sorry if I am wrong. Yes. To be exact, both the data partition and the Windows disk seem to be unmounted, but get mounted when I click on them at the left-menu, while being at the Home folder.

Comment: @gsamaras Good, click on the data partition to mount it and then please post the path to the partition. It should be something like /media/gsamaras/somethingelse

Comment: `/media/gsamaras/a6cd1464-abf1-4a7b-b4a2-61f584d4cb32`

Comment: @gsamaras Awesome! Run the following command to gain ownership of the partition and all contained files: sudo chown -R gsamaras:gsamaras  "/media/gsamaras/a6cd1464-abf1-4a7b-b4a2-61f584d4cb32"

Comment: Hurray! That worked mchid, please update your answer. ;) **Note that I did not used the double quotes!**

Comment: @gsamaras Here, the quotation marks don't make a difference although it is a good habit to use them.

Answer (score -1):

I don't if this will work in your situation but whats the harm in trying right ?

why not create a user with the same name and uid as that hadoopuser

```
sudo -i
#adduser -u 1001 hadoopuser
```

then try to access
if didn't wroked which is the way it should
become root

```
sudo -i
#chmod 666 foldername/
#chmod 666 foldername/*
#chown -R yourlocaluser:yourlocaluser foldername/
```

Comment: Why you have some lines commented in your answer? No I want hadoopuser for a clean installation of my cluster, do not want to lose him in a fight like that...He's like Achilles.