# Home folder opens again

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, files, icons

I have [a mounted partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725444/help-me-win-this-war), where my data lie. I click on the folder icon and it opens. I go to the 196 GB Volume (that's the place) and it opens. I open a file with gedit.

Now, when I want to go back to the folder, I click on the folder icon again and instead of giving me the Volume, it opens a new folder (the home). When I click again on the icon, I am getting both File windows and I have to select which I want, where I am interested only in the Volume.

How to get rid of that behaviour? i.e. when I have the folder of the Volume open and I click on the Files icon, the Volume folder to pop-up (since it's already open), instead of the home folder.

Comment: Since my answer of defeat was downvoted, I would like the downvoter to *at least* make an attempt to answer this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I will have to live with it. A nice approach is to open the media in a New Tab. That way, it won't open a new Folder, but you will need an extra Tab open of course.