# How to change permissions" Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: system-installation, permissions, nautilus

I am the owner and sole user of my desktop computer.
I need to create a NEW directory in a specific folder called  /opt.
In MS Windows, we (users) are asked beforehand where a software is to be installed. 
Here with Ubuntu, I installed wps office6 (from .deb) and after struggling, I found out that this program was installed on : 
Other Locations > Computer > /opt .
Now I need to create a folder to install the French spell check dictionary in the path: Other Locations > Computer > opt /office6/dicts/spellcheck. 
However .....!
I do not have permission to create a directory in / opt and I get the message: 
"You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions".

Questions:

1. How do I change the permission PERMANENTLY for my entire « Computer » or at least for /opt and / media folders ?
2. How can I control and select or be asked where a program is to be installed before it gets installed on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS ?

Thanks in advance for prompt clear answers ;-)

NOTE : the command « gsku nautilus » is NOT working.

["You are not the owner..." message when trying to access folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150028/you-are-not-the-owner-message-when-trying-to-access-folder)

Reference:
https://help.wps.com/articles/How-to-add-thirdparty-spell-check-dictionary-in-wps-office

Comment: Do **not** do this. You don't want to change permissions on folders under `/`. My suggestion would be to read about [sudo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo)

Comment: Changing permissions is a VERY bad idea. Use `sudo` instead.

Comment: How can I then use sudo  terminal command  to  create NEW directory called "fr_FR" in the path: office6/dicts/spellcheck  ?

Comment: Question #1 is essentially: "I want to change all the fasteners on my car to M3 screws". Doing it will make your car inoperable. Permissions are a flexible system that protects you from intruders *and* from your own folly. Learn to work *with* permissions.

Comment: Question #2: In a deb-based or snap-based system, you don't get to choose where applications get installed to. The .deb or .snap specifies the install locations. This is, of course, somewhat different from Windows. Ubuntu is not a Windows clone. It works differently.

Comment: To  user535733 :

Comment: To user535733 : the whole idea about great things like Ubuntu is FREEDOM. I was able to build my own computer, picking and choosing what piece or part is suitable for my needs. While hardware components advanced to more flexibility (...), software and _software development_ or programming are still enslaving us with permissions and costs. I still prefer to be the master of my own follies than follow others'  ;-)  Knowing and editing folders' location should remain basic common sense.

Comment: André, if you want to learn about permissions I can recommend "Linux Commands for Beginners 09 - Understanding Permissions on LearnLinux.tv on Youtube. However the guys above are right, please learn how to work with linux in the way it is designed to be used. To copy a file into a directory that your user does not have permission for simply use sudo. i.e. sudo cp path_to_source path_to_target. You will be asked to enter your password and it should work.